# View optimization

Tags: optimization, view, sql-server-2014

As you see below I have a select from a view and my problem is that it takes too long to execute the whole view - around 4min.

The problem is at the `FULL OUTER JOIN` because it takes about 55% of time!

I can't find/see a viable solution. If you have any idea, it will be much appreciated!

```
SELECT CAST('1' + CAST(c.ContractNumber AS VARCHAR) + RIGHT('0000'+CAST(ISNULL(p.billTRANNO, p.TRANNO) AS VARCHAR),5) AS BIGINT) AS PaymentID,
    CAST('1' + CAST(c.ContractNumber AS VARCHAR) AS BIGINT) AS ContractID,
    CAST(ISNULL(p.billTRDT,p.corrPTRNEFF ) AS DATE) AS PaymentBillingDate,
    CAST(l.INSTTO AS DATE) AS PaymentDueDate,
    CAST ((CASE WHEN p.BATCTRCDE IN ('B216', 'T642', 'T679', 'B9H2', 'T693', 'T680') THEN p.TRANSACTION_DATE END) AS DATE) AS PaymentDate, 
    CAST((CASE WHEN p.BATCTRCDE = 'B216' AND c.StatCode+c.PStatCode IN ('IFWP','IFDW') THEN l.INSTAMT01
              WHEN p.BATCTRCDE IN ('T642', 'T679', 'B9H2', 'T693', 'T680') THEN rtrn.ORIGAMT END) AS DECIMAL (15,2)) AS PaymentAmount, 
    c.Currency,
    CAST((CASE WHEN p.BATCTRCDE IN ('T679', 'B9H2', 'T693', 'T680', 'T642') THEN 'P'
                WHEN l.PAYFLAG IS NOT NULL THEN l.PAYFLAG WHEN billTRANNO IS NOT NULL THEN 'O' ELSE 'P' END) AS CHAR(2)) AS PaymentStateCode,
    CAST((CASE WHEN p.BATCTRCDE IN ('T679', 'B9H2', 'T693', 'T680') THEN 'TU'
                WHEN p.BATCTRCDE = 'T642' AND c.ProductCode IN ('1S0', 'XS0', 'INV', 'IND', '1S1', 'XS1', 'PS1', 'PS2', 'SE0', '1S2') THEN 'SP'
                WHEN p.BATCTRCDE = 'T642' AND c.ProductCode NOT IN ('1S0', 'XS0', 'INV', 'IND', '1S1', 'XS1', 'PS1', 'PS2', 'SE0', '1S2') THEN 'IS'
                WHEN p.BATCTRCDE = 'B216' OR p.billTRANNO IS NOT NULL THEN 'RP' END) AS CHAR(2)) AS PaymentTypeCode,
    1 as BusinessLineCode
FROM tmpContract_BaseData c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ISNULL(p.ContractNumber, bill.ContractNumber) ContractNumber, p.TRANNO, p.PTRNEFF, p.BATCTRCDE, p.TRANSACTION_DATE,
                        bill.TRANNO billTRANNO, bill.PTRNEFF billPTRNEFF, bill.TRANSACTION_DATE billTRDT, corr.PTRNEFF corrPTRNEFF
                FROM (SELECT ContractNumber, TRANNO, PTRNEFF, BATCTRCDE, TRANSACTION_DATE 
                        FROM dbo.PTRN 
                        WHERE BATCTRCDE IN ('T679', 'T642', 'B216', 'B9H2','T693','T680') and VALIDFLAG='1') p 
                    FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT ContractNumber, PTRNEFF, TRANSACTION_DATE, BATCTRCDE, TRANNO 
                                    FROM dbo.PTRN 
                                    WHERE BATCTRCDE in ('B503') AND VALIDFLAG='1') bill 
                        ON bill.ContractNumber=p.ContractNumber AND bill.PTRNEFF=p.PTRNEFF AND p.BATCTRCDE = 'B216' AND bill.TRANNO<p.TRANNO
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ContractNumber, PTRNEFF, TRANSACTION_DATE, BATCTRCDE, TRANNO 
                    ,RANK() over (partition by ContractNumber, PTRNEFF, TRANSACTION_DATE, BATCTRCDE order by TRANNO) as NrCrt
                FROM dbo.PTRN 
                WHERE BATCTRCDE in ('Z791') AND VALIDFLAG='1') corr 
                    ON corr.ContractNumber=p.ContractNumber AND corr.PTRNEFF=p.PTRNEFF AND p.BATCTRCDE = 'B216' AND corr.TRANNO>p.TRANNO and NrCrt = 1
                ) p on p.ContractNumber = c.ContractNumber
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LINS l ON l.ContractNumber=c.ContractNumber AND dbo.ParseDateNullInvalid(l.INSTFROM,10)=ISNULL(p.billPTRNEFF, p.corrPTRNEFF)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ContractNumber, TRANNO, SUM(ORIGAMT) AS ORIGAMT FROM dbo.RTRN WHERE SACSCODE='LP' AND SACSTYP='S'
GROUP BY ContractNumber, TRANNO) rtrn ON rtrn.ContractNumber=p.ContractNumber AND rtrn.TRANNO=p.TRANNO
WHERE c.BusinessLineCode='1'
```

Comment: Horse, you're right...I was thinking something else.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? (Your example is invalid standard SQL) -  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: You should also provide the execution plan for your query the definition of the views and all involved tables including their index definitions. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps